# Why am I getting 5 to 8 FPS when using a KVM (Keyboard Video Mouse), but 30 FPS when using PuTTY?

Tags: server, dell

My system is a Dell PowerEdge T710 running Headless Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, now the problem is, when I try to to login to the server using iDRAC (Internal Dell Remote Access Controller), which opens up a Java KVM (Keyboard Video Mouse) console, I get around 5 to 8 FPS, but when I login to the server using SSH Putty, I get around 30 FPS.

Anyone have any answers to this question?

Comment: That is quite common at those speeds.  I have worked around thousands of these servers in a data center.  There really isn't a lot of configuration you can do, and it would be at the system level and not the OS level.  The OS has no control of the iDRAC on the system.  You can try an iDRAC and or BIOS update for the system.

Answer (score 1):

Java is slow, plus KVM needs to send graphics image of the screen. Probably not using any intelligent method for detecting changed areas of the screen, but just sending the whole image frame by frame.

SSH is a text-based connection, talking about FPS here doesn't even make much sense as you transfer pure ASCII text only and not any image. There is hundreds of times less data to transfer using SSH than KVM.

Comment: the KVM console is actually text based, there is no GFX being that I'm using headless Ubuntu server, and at the top of the KVM virtual console it shows the FPS, which is around 5 to 8, and everything that appears on that console is heavily lagged.  that's why I use PuTTY instead.

Comment: So that's probably issue with Java itself being slow. Plus iDRAC itself can be pretty slow, these management devices usually have weak processors as they don't need much computing power. This type of connection is usually used as "emergency" one, when you don't have a network connection on OS level, for example when reinstalling the OS. SSH is a normal way to connect.

Comment: So, basically, it's better (after using KVM to boot server) to use PuTTY rather than the virtual console?

Comment: And despite the fact that you see only text on the console, KVM connection can be actually graphic one. The basic job of KVM is to transfer exact image of the screen, so the connection basically should be graphic. It's an easy way to check this. If you see fonts of exactly the same shape on KVM connection as on the physical monitor attached directly to server, then the connection is definitely graphic.

Comment: Yes, after the server is booted up and working normally, SSH is the regular way to access it. Often you don't have KVM access at all. For example when working with servers in the cloud, all you have is SSH.

Comment: In the KVM, I see exactly what is on the server monitor but a lot slower, seeing the server monitor during a boot, everything scrolls at super speed, but when I see it in the KVM, everything is super slow.

Comment: Then it's a graphic connection, and it may be slow due to all three reasons (lot of data to process, Java being slow, slow processor in iDRAC). Manufactirers don't care about the effectiveness of that connection, as it is - as I wrote - meant for emergency situations only.

Comment: @MichealSaunders You can ssh through the iDRAC and use the console or you can enable Serial Over Lan (SOL) which gives you less control as it is really just a passthrough instead.  Using the console can at least give you some control. You can also use ipmitool remotely to send commands to the host as well.  One thing to remember though is that Dell only gives 5 simultaneous connections through the iDRAC/BMC.

Comment: Ok, thanks for everyone's help, it looks like I'll just use iDRAC for remote power on/off, but use PuTTY for regular access, and being that the KVM is not a Kernel Virtual Machine, but instead it's a Keyboard Video and Mouse virtual console.

Comment: @Terrance using the serial console over LAN, don't you need serial interface to be enabled in the OS? Otherwise, you'll be able to see BIOS boot-up messages only and then after the OS boots the screen will be blank. I don't know iDRAC, but that was the case with iLO on HP servers (which BTW is quite efficient in KVM mode but has its own dedicated application for this)

Comment: @MichealSaunders of course, KVM as Kernel Virtual Machine is a completely different thing :)

Comment: @raj Yes, and it is easy enough by adding `console=ttyS1` to the kernel line in GRUB for `console com2`.  I am also familiar with iLO as well.  My first go in a data center was with the HP BL460s, DL350 and DL360s.  Also when you ssh to the iDRAC to see the output of the boot it is `console com2` to start it.

Comment: Hmmm, what I don't understand is why Dell would want slow server management tools, iDRAC is an added module that connects to the motherboard and has it's own dedicated 10/100T NIC, along with it's own IP address, so I would have though for a remote system like iDRAC, Dell would have at least made it almost instant.

Comment: They don't slow it down intentionally. But they have to put some effort in order to make it fast and probably they decided it's not worth the effort. In text mode (SSH), every **character** sent is 1 or 2 bytes. In KVM mode, every **pixel** sent is 3 bytes in 24-bit color mode. Assuming only 1024x768 screen resolution, if you don't use any image compression algorithms, it's 2.25 megabytes **per each frame** to transfer. And if you use image compression algorithms, they can be slow on low-end CPUs like the one inside iDRAC.